# Global dependency repositories - Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm currently using composer to manage my project's dependencies on my development environment and it works wonders, however I'm a bit lost when I deploy to production because many of my projects share quite a few of dependencies (Symfony, Doctrine, log4php ...) and I feel silly uploading them over and over and over again. Is there any way to configure symphony to use a 'central destination' or something like that?

I already tried changing the destination directory to a 'shared' directory, and tried configuring a couple of projects there, but composer deletes unused packages.

Answer (score 0):

Your projects may share the same libraries, but do they share the same versions of these libraries?

And what if you decide to update one of these libraries? You have to test ALL your projects if nothing broke, instead of only the one project you are currently working on.

And what if your one project really needs an updated version because of some feature, but updating breaks another project because there was also an incompatible change.

Because of all this Composer decided to maintain the software dependencies per project, not globally, because maintaining a global set of libraries is a huge pain (some reasons given above) and shouldn't be done if it can be avoided.